# pandas: shrinking df with composition of values in columns by multi column index

Tags: pandas

Can you help me with this problem:
i want to make the dataframe  with unique values for the columns ['category_1', 'category_2', 'level_1'] (index) and compose with space between the values from columns ['color', 'Name', 'Name_2'] the values from columns ['m','k'] always has same value before and after compose
i give df before and after better understanding
before:

```
     color   Name  Name_2 category_1 category_2  level_1    m    k
0    black    Tom    Karl          a          x        2  asd   hf
1    green    Tom    Karl          a          x        2  asd   hf
2      red    red  johans          b          x        2   xg  cvb
3      red    tan  johans          b          x        2   xg  cvb
4    white  krish    bill          a          x        3   et  cvh
5    white  krish    jack          a          x        3   et  cvh
6   orange  krish    bill          a          x        3   et  cvh
7   orange  krish    jack          a          x        3   et  cvh
8     jack   jack   frank          b          x        3  fgd  gfh
9     jack    bac   frank          b          x        3  fgd  gfh
10    blue    bob     teo          b          y        3  dfg  cvh
11   green    bob     teo          b          y        3  dfg  cvh
```

after:

```
          color      Name     Name_2 category_1 category_2  level_1    m    k
0   black green       Tom       Karl          a          x        2  asd   hf
1           red   red tan     johans          b          x        2   xg  cvb
2  white orange     krish  bill jack          a          x        3   et  cvh
3          jack  jack bac      frank          b          x        3  fgd  gfh
4   blue  green       bob        teo          b          y        3  dfg  cvh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `'category_1', 'category_2', 'level_1', 'm', 'k'`, setting the `sort` and `as_index` parameters to `False`, and then use a lambda function inside a call to [`.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) to join the unique values from the other columns with a whitespace.
- Chain [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to reorder the columns.

```
out = (df.groupby(['category_1', 'category_2', 'level_1', 'm', 'k'], 
                  sort=False, 
                  as_index=False)
       .agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x.unique()))
       .loc[:, df.columns])

out

          color      Name     Name_2 category_1 category_2  level_1    m    k
0   black green       Tom       Karl          a          x        2  asd   hf
1           red   red tan     johans          b          x        2   xg  cvb
2  white orange     krish  bill jack          a          x        3   et  cvh
3          jack  jack bac      frank          b          x        3  fgd  gfh
4    blue green       bob        teo          b          y        3  dfg  cvh
```